# MS Graph authentication using python

Tags: python, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to write a Python code where I would like to access my calendar and retrieve my schedule.
Not able to get through the authentication phase.
Seen and tested many examples, but all require running a local server where I browse locally and need to click a button and then enter my credentials.
Aiming to perform all of this inside my Python code.

Comment: You should include more details in your questions. Sample code of what you've tried so far, screenshots/errors of what's going on and details on what you expect. Check out the StackOverflow guidelines for asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Let's say in my Python code I am forming this kind of link, with the redirect URI and the client ID:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=<uri>&client_id=<id>

This will result in a response which will require to enter my cloud credentials.

I would like to do this without human intervention, i.e. from the Python code.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this one of two ways:

1. Using **Resource Owner Password Credential flow** - This allows you to pass the username and password to Azure AD. Gotcha's here are if there's any extra thing on the auth flow (consent, MFA, password reset) you'll just get a failure.
2. Using **Client Credentials flow** - This one requires [admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-apps-permissions-consent). Also, you have to be really careful about this one as this client will have access to ALL info about all users. This should only be used with secure clients, not clients that other users have access to.

Here's a code snippet that showcases both of these:

```
import adal
import requests

tenant = "contoso.com"
client_id = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"

username = "foo@contoso.com"
password = "mypassword"

authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant
RESOURCE = "https://graph.microsoft.com"

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority)

# Use this for Client Credentials
#token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
#    RESOURCE,
#    client_id,
#    client_secret
#    )

# Use this for Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC)  
token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(RESOURCE, username, password, client_id);

graph_api_endpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0{0}'

# /me only works with ROPC, for Client Credentials you'll need /<UsersObjectId/
request_url = graph_api_endpoint.format('/me')
headers = { 
'User-Agent' : 'python_tutorial/1.0',
'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(token["accessToken"]),
'Accept' : 'application/json',
'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(url = request_url, headers = headers)
print (response.content)
```

Comment: Finally! The 'client id/client secret' route works for me after registering the app in Azure AD.

Comment: what is `consent` in the ROPC flow? I have admin access, where I should grant consent if that's a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Will try the above...

What I did to solve this was using this example - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/app_only

The problem was asking for the right permissions for the app in Azure.