# retrieve token other than with a web app

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I followed the code here:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python3-connect-rest-sample

in order to be able to access excel sheets on my OneDrive folder from a **remote machine with no UI.**

The issue is that I need to set up a flask app on my machine in order to get the `access_token`.

In particular, this means that I need to start the flask server, manually open a browser, navigate to `http://localhost:5000`, which starts the OAuth process and retrieves the token. Then, I send over the retrieved `access_token` over to my remote instance where I can continue with the work.

I could automate all of this with selenium, perhaps, but I feel this is overcomplicating things way too much. Surely, there must be a better way of doing this in a reasonable way?

Comment: Speedwise, Scrapy is faster than Selenium and easier to use, if you can't find other solutions, I suggest you look into scrapy.

Comment: I think you may have missed the point of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can obtain a token without a UI that prompts for username & password and without the auth code dance:

- **Using Resource Owner Password Credential flow** - This allows you to pass the username and password to Azure AD. Gotcha's here are if there's any extra thing on the auth flow (consent, MFA, password reset) you'll just get a failure.
- **Using Client Credentials flow** - This one requires admin consent. Also, you have to be really careful about this one as this client will have access to ALL info about all users. This should only be used with secure clients, not clients that other users have access to.

Here's a code snippet that showcases both of these:

```
import adal
import requests

tenant = "contoso.com"
client_id = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"

username = "foo@contoso.com"
password = "mypassword"

authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant
RESOURCE = "https://graph.microsoft.com"

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority)

# Use this for Client Credentials
#token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
#    RESOURCE,
#    client_id,
#    client_secret
#)

# Use this for Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC)  
token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(RESOURCE, username, password, client_id);

graph_api_endpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0{0}'

# /me only works with ROPC, for Client Credentials you'll need /<UsersObjectId/
request_url = graph_api_endpoint.format('/me')
headers = { 
    'User-Agent' : 'python_tutorial/1.0',
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(token["accessToken"]),
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(url = request_url, headers = headers)
```

**Note:** I'm reusing my answer to a very similar question: [MS Graph authentication using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624144/ms-graph-authentication-using-python/42704710#42704710)

Comment: `acquire_token_with_client_credentials` did it for me. I get "AdalError: Unsupported wstrust endpoint version. Current support version is wstrust2005 or wstrust13" when using `acquire_token_with_username_password`. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sounds like you hit one other caveat of Resource Owner Password Credential flow: doesn't work for lots of the different possible federation setups.

Comment: hi again. So it turns out this does not work because I am not specifying the scope parameters. This looked like this `request_token_params={'scope': 'User.Read Mail.Send Files.Read Files.ReadWrite', 'expires_in':'86400'},`

Is there a way around this?